# Black default.png and app rejection?

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval

Xcode automatically added black default.png to my project . I didn't change it and I've sent it to the apple , it's waiting for review . Is it a rejection reason ? The default.png s can be just black or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A black default image will not cause your app to be rejected. I have had apps accepted with no default image at all - if the app starts quickly enough, or there is no appropriate content for a launch image, then you don't need one.

Rant: Using the larger default image to indicate that an iPhone app works on the iPhone 5 is (IMO) a pretty poor decision - a key in the info plist would be much more sensible. As devices get faster, and resolution gets higher, launch images are becoming ridiculous. A universal app supporting iPhone 3, 4, 5, iPad and retina iPad will have megabytes of basically wasted space, to support an image that is shown for milliseconds. It was needed when devices were slower, but not really now.

Comment: I agree re poor design decision in determining user interfaces based upon presence or absence of launch screens. That _is_ silly.

Answer (score 0):

Section 10.6 of the [App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#user-interface) says:

> 10.6 Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected

Apparently people are getting apps approved without launch screens (even though they're listed as [required](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) in the HIG and I would not have thought that a blank screen would qualify), so we'll keep our fingers crossed!

Comment: I hope it won't be a problem . It's just the default.png , we will see

Comment: The interface of your app is not related to the launch image. This answer is misleading.

Comment: @SalihOzdemir Good luck! Let us know how it goes!

Comment: I saw that part in the HIG too... _shhhh_, I'm trying not to draw attention to it! (It was a while ago, they may have tightened up the procedures, but it would get checked and rejected at the first, automatic phase, I think)

Comment: It was approved guys :) we talked about then it was approved in 20 mins . Thank you Rob , jrturton !